# Can mongoexport --csv export fields with special characters such as a slash?

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

mongoexport v2.6.4, when used with --csv, seems to ignore fields with slashes in them and emit an incorrect CSV header row:

```
mongoexport ... --csv -f 'id,meta.og/url,meta.twitter/url'
```

outputs the CSV header row

```
id,meta.og
```

The mongo shell has no problem isolating fields with slashes in them.

Any ways to work around this without pulling the entire JSON document?

Comment: Try putting the field name in quotes if it has special characters.

Comment: @wdberkeley I could not find a way to do this that worked. However, it did work when I added them to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked was to use a field file with the `--fieldFile` option.