# Can mongoexport --csv export fields with special characters?

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

I have problems exporting the field below from Mongo. `mongoexport` leaves it empty when the source field contains this string:

```
"campaign_name" : "[1604ES96774] APP ABRIL FACEBOOK (47012) Descargas app_AudienceNetwork"
```

Please, Do you have any suggestion? I think there could be problems with [] or () characters. Any way to escape them?

It was suggested to use `--fieldFile` option (reference: [Can mongoexport --csv export fields with special characters such as a slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887965/can-mongoexport-csv-export-fields-with-special-characters-such-as-a-slash/37321929#37321929)) , but this option is for including the list of the fields as external file instead of using the list of fields...

Thanks in advance.
Richard.

(I include this as new question because it was requested by the admin @ ρяσѕρєя)